# How can I configure sites like subfolder on nginx?

Tags: nginx, drupal

I want to configure 3 sites on nginx ([Drupal](https://www.drupal.org) sites)

```
www.domain.com               == served in ==>   /var/www/domain.com/
www.domain.com/folder01/     == served in ==>   /var/www/folder01/
www.domain.com/folder02/     == served in ==>   /var/www/folder02/
```

I know to configure the first, but i don't how do it the others.

Comment: Did you try anything? Or are you totally lost? :)

Comment: i had tried it, searching in google, but i couldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to know about `location` directive (see [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)).

In your case:

```
server {
  # server_name, listen, etc. - general settings

  root /var/www/domain.com;
  # some drupal-specific lines

  location /folder01 {
    root /var/www/folder01/;
    # some drupal-specific lines
  }

  location /folder02 {
    root /var/www/folder02/;
    # some drupla-specific lines
  }

}
```